# ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key stored to ContentRootPath does not work on different machines

Tags: asp.net-core, data-protection

I have Setup a Database for developing that is available in the local network.
I implemented the Dataprotection Api to encrypt some of the sensitive information of my models(Entity Framework), before saving it to the database.
In Startup I configured it like this:

```
var keysfolder = Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, "Keys");
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keysfolder));
```

The Key is in the folder,not protected and shared in the repository because it is only for Test Data.
I can access the data in my app on 2 different Linux machines but on one Windows PC I get a Invalid Payload exception.
They share the same commit and use the same purpose strings.
So I must have failed to understand it. I thought that I can backup the keys and the database in production and redeploy, if necesarry on a different machine without loosing the data.
Can anybody explain why I can´t use the key on the Windows PC?

Comment: Do you mean you the keys folder is insider your project? Could you please share the details exception? It seems that windows and linux will not use different data protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution to this problem.
I found the answer here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-the-payload/ba-p/1919096

You have to call SetApplicationName when registering DataProtection:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName("MyApp")
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keysfolder))
```